# Select a specific column from laravel eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

How do I select the column `Field` from the `FormFactor` model? I want to select only one column from the recordset.

```
public function ApiFormFactorDetails()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\FormFactor','formfactor_id')->select('name');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the name in array: `->select(['name']);`?

Comment: yap i tried but it's not working giving me null

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent models share pretty much the same syntax as the query builder. From [the query builder documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results):

> If you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the value method. This method will return the value of the column directly:
>
> `$email = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');`

In your case:

```
public function ApiFormFactorDetails()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\FormFactor','formfactor_id')->value('name');
}
```

Comment: public function apiGetFormFactorDetails()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\FormFactor','formfactor_id')->value('name');
    }

I tried this but its end up as a error : 

ERROR : -

FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 451: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the way you are doing should work fine. You can keep the code in the function:

```
public function ApiFormFactorDetails()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\FormFactor','formfactor_id')->select('name');
}
```

And then, call it like this:

```
$object->ApiFormFactorDetails;
```

The return will have only `name` as attribute.

Comment: but it's also giving me null 

 #relations: array:1 [▼
                "apiGetFormFactorDetails" => null

Comment: Try to change to `return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\FormFactor','formfactor_id');` and check if it is returning anything when you call `$object->ApiFormFactorDetails;`. It must return something if there is any relation between the object and a FormFactor entity.

Comment: I do that it's returning all record set but not the single one what i want